# Как объявить переменную через запрос?

Tags: sql, запрос

Объявляю переменную через запрос

```
DECLARE @CountCodes INT

SELECT @CountCodes = 
(SELECT COUNT (c.Code) FROM Employees AS c
WHERE c.[Year] = @year AND c.[Month] = @month 
AND c.EmployeeId = @EmpId)
```

Далее использую ее в расчете

```
SELECT SUM(m.fact)/SUM(m.plan*@CountCodes)*100
```

Возвращается ошибка, что на ноль делить нельзя, хотя отдельно запрос выдает положительное число.
Где я ошибся?

Comment: СУБД укажите точно, включая версию.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка не тут, если верить вашим словам. Поставьте проверку на делении во избежании ошибки. И приведите полный листинг с результатами промежуточных вычислений. Думаю после ответ изменится